# Google+ Activities Search not returning results

Tags: python, google-api, google-plus, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to utilize the Google+ API's. So far they are working, but I am wanting to search public posts. I am on their [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) page which allows you to try out the API live. However, I am not getting any results for anything I try other than the query "python". I have tried a bunch of terms and am receiving no results. When I search through the G+ site I get plenty of results for things like "oil" or "technology". I have also written python scripts which are returning the no results. Am I misunderstanding this, or is it broken. Thanks

Comment: You might have to repeat the search a couple of times. I just tried it on the docs example search and the first time returned no results but subsequent tries had results.

Comment: yeah I've been trying that and still no luck